# PHP file_get_contents - check json file if ready and uploaded

Tags: php

i need get data from json file, but first i need check if file it's ok and ready.

The json file are uploaded to my server every 5 minutes from a external station device.

Sometimes i get problem to read file because it's on upload, and file_get_contents not get file as it should. how i control if file it's ok and ready, and not in upload process?

it's possible check the file, and retry until file it's udploaded and ready?

my function to get json data.

```
$arrContextOptions = array(
    "ssl" => array(
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
    )
);
$datawds5 = file_get_contents( "https://website/template_wds5.json", false, stream_context_create( $arrContextOptions ) );
$wds5 = json_decode( $datawds5 );
```

Comment: In your case I would use [flock()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock) on upload script and this one.

Comment: To elaborate on what Markus is saying, it is probably better for this to be handled on the upload side of things if possible. That way an “I’m done” can be handled and the file can be unlocked, moved, etc. If that’s not an option (maybe the upload is over FTP) your only recourse is to try reading the file. If it fails to parse, try again in _n_ seconds. Keep track of the file size each time you fail, too. If it is the same twice in a row, the file is probably corrupt.